# How to cut inner div to its parent div size?

Tags: css, html

I have a square div (called "square") and trying to put another div ("caption") inside the "square". But the caption goes outside the square boundaries! How to cut its size to the exact boundaries of the parent div?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: #000000;
        }
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }
        div.square {
            background-color: #1BA1E2;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 44px;
            height: 44px;
            margin: 0 6px 0 9px;
        }
        div.caption {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 15px 0 0 3px;
            padding: 0;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-size: 24px;
        }
        span.description {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: bottom;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <a href="page">
            <div class="square">
                <div class="caption">
                    Caption
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="description">
                Description
            </span>
        </a>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

In this case, `Caption` should be cut to `Cap`+ 1/2`t` inside the blue box (something like WP7 style). And a description alongside.

Comment: why don't you just give the caption div the same width as the container? 44px

Comment: Added `width: 44px;` to the above code for `div.caption` - didn't help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put `overflow:hidden` in the styles for `div.square`.  This will cause the caption to cut off at the boundaries of the box.

[Running example](http://jsfiddle.net/TzRYj/)

Comment: what would we do if the parent had a `position:absolute;`